# Upsampling using SMOTE in python

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, data-science, imblearn

I am trying to use SMOTE in python to handle highly imbalanced data set. After splitting the data set into train and test I generate synthetic samples using SMOTE. Then I use xgboost algorithm on the SMOTE generated data. My model output is to predict the probability for the original dataset. But after implementing SMOTE the number of samples have been increased and how do I get back the original data set to predict the probabilities?  **Code as below**:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X_final, Y_final, test_size=0.1, random_state = 27)  
sm = SMOTE(random_state=27, ratio=1.0)  
X_final_sm, Y_final_sm = sm.fit_sample(X_train, y_train)  
smote_xgb = XGBClassifier().fit(X_final_sm, Y_final_sm) 
smote_pred = smote_xgb.predict(X_final_sm)  
smote_pred_prob = smote_xgb.predict_proba(X_final_sm)
```

Comment: you can take a take copy of it before applying the SMOTE and then use it during validation

Comment: I am generating synthetic samples using **X_train, y_train** and then fitting the model using the generated **X_final_sm, Y_final_sm**.
But when I try to predict the test dataset - `smote_xgb.predict(X_test)` I get `ValueError: feature_names mismatch`. Does SMOTE jumble the columns?

Comment: Complete error as below : `ValueError: feature_names mismatch: ['f0', 'f1', 'f2', 'f3', 'f4', 'f5', 'f6', 'f7', 'f8', 'f9', 'f10'] ['corresponding column names']
expected f0, f2, f9, f8, f6, f10, f3, f1, f4, f5, f7 in input data
training data did not have the following fields: <corresponding column names>`